# Error: Can't find npm module 'moment'

Tags: javascript, meteor, heroku, npm

I have a Meteor app that runs perfectly on localhost, but when I deploy it to a remote `heroku` server, I get the following errors.

(I am implementing [this](http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp2/ionic/setup))

Any ideas how to fix this please?

```
2016-09-09T13:26:02.533532+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `.meteor/heroku_build/bin/node .meteor/heroku_build/app/main.js`
2016-09-09T13:26:06.806440+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-09-09T13:26:06.813921+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-09-09T13:26:06.704013+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
2016-09-09T13:26:06.704027+00:00 app[web.1]:                        throw(ex);
2016-09-09T13:26:06.704028+00:00 app[web.1]:                        ^
2016-09-09T13:26:06.704029+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-09-09T13:26:06.704030+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Can't find npm module 'moment'. Did you forget to call 'Npm.depends' in package.js within the 'modules-runtime' package?
2016-09-09T13:26:06.704031+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Npm.require (/app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/boot.js:198:17)
2016-09-09T13:26:06.704032+00:00 app[web.1]:     at options.fallback (packages/modules-runtime/modules-runtime.js:21:1)
2016-09-09T13:26:06.704032+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:88:1)
2016-09-09T13:26:06.704033+00:00 app[web.1]:     at meteorInstall.server.main.js (server/main.ts:1:19)
2016-09-09T13:26:06.704035+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:82:1)
2016-09-09T13:26:06.704035+00:00 app[web.1]:     at server/main.ts:65:4
2016-09-09T13:26:06.704036+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/boot.js:292:10
2016-09-09T13:26:06.704036+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Array.forEach (native)
```

If I `heroku run bash` to log onto heroku. In `/app/typings/globals` I see the following:

```
es6-collections  es6-promise  google-maps  google.maps  meteor  moment
```

This seems to match what is on the Windows localhost:

[image]

Moments also exist in `node_modules`

[image]

Here is `my node_modules\moment\package.js`:

```
var profile = {
    resourceTags: {
        ignore: function(filename, mid){
            // only include moment/moment
            return mid != "moment/moment";
        },
        amd: function(filename, mid){
            return /\.js$/.test(filename);
        }
    }
};
```

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "^2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@ionic/cloud-angular": "^0.4.0",
    "angular2-meteor": "^0.6.2",
    "angular2-moment": "^0.8.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "ionic-angular": "^2.0.0-beta.11",
    "ionic-native": "1.3.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "meteor-client-side": "^1.3.4",
    "moment": "^2.14.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "socket.io": "^1.4.8",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
```

snippet from logs when deploying:

```
remote: -----> Building Meteor app with ROOT_URL: https://git.heroku.com/remote-thewhozoo.git
remote: server/collections.ts (1, 21): Cannot find module 'meteor/mongo'.
remote: server/collections.ts (2, 29): Cannot find module 'api/models'.
remote: server/methods.ts (1, 22): Cannot find module 'meteor/meteor'.
remote: server/methods.ts (2, 28): Cannot find module 'meteor/check'.
remote: server/main.ts (1, 25): Cannot find module 'moment'.
remote: server/main.ts (2, 22): Cannot find module 'meteor/meteor'.
remote:
remote: Unable to resolve some modules:
remote:
remote:   "moment" in /tmp/build_29ec6195d953bd56c0670f7d9ee489a4/server/main.js
remote: (os.linux.x86_64)
remote:
remote: If you notice problems related to these missing modules, consider running:
remote:
remote:   meteor npm install --save moment
remote:
remote: -----> Moving built slug to /tmp/build_29ec6195d953bd56c0670f7d9ee489a4/.meteor/heroku_build/app
remote: -----> Installing npm production dependencies on built slug
remote:
remote: > fibers@1.0.13 install /tmp/build_29ec6195d953bd56c0670f7d9ee489a4/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/node_modules/fibers
remote: > node build.js || nodejs build.js
remote:
remote: `linux-x64-v8-4.5` exists; testing
remote: Binary is fine; exiting
remote:
remote: > meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 install /tmp/build_29ec6195d953bd56c0670f7d9ee489a4/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server
remote: > node npm-rebuild.js
remote:
remote: {
remote:   "meteor-dev-bundle": "0.0.0",
remote:   "npm": "3.10.6",
remote:   "ares": "1.10.1-DEV",
remote:   "http_parser": "2.7.0",
remote:   "icu": "56.1",
remote:   "modules": "46",
remote:   "node": "4.5.0",
remote:   "openssl": "1.0.2h",
remote:   "uv": "1.9.1",
remote:   "v8": "4.5.103.37",
remote:   "zlib": "1.2.8"
remote: }
```

index.d.ts

```
declare module 'moment' {
    var moment: moment.MomentStatic;
    export = moment;
}
```

I do have symbolic links in the root of the meteor project:

[image]

**UPDATE**

I have found the problem I think, but I am not 100% sure how to solve it yet.

The issue is that the symbolic links are pointing to directories that exist locally, but not on the remote server.

[image]

**UPDATE**

I remove all symbolic links, and have the files there instead, deploy, and I still get the same error when the server tries to start:

```
2016-09-11T15:23:06.155551+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-09-11T15:23:09.146909+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `.meteor/heroku_build/bin/node .meteor/heroku_build/app/main.js`
2016-09-11T15:23:13.712742+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-09-11T15:23:13.640003+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
2016-09-11T15:23:13.640048+00:00 app[web.1]:                        throw(ex);
2016-09-11T15:23:13.640073+00:00 app[web.1]:                        ^
2016-09-11T15:23:13.640075+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Can't find npm module 'moment'. Did you forget to call 'Npm.depends' in package.js within the 'modules-runtime' package?
2016-09-11T15:23:13.640076+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Npm.require (/app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/boot.js:198:17)
2016-09-11T15:23:13.640077+00:00 app[web.1]:     at options.fallback (packages/modules-runtime/modules-runtime.js:21:1)
2016-09-11T15:23:13.640078+00:00 app[web.1]:     at meteorInstall.server.main.js (server/main.ts:1:19)
2016-09-11T15:23:13.640079+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:82:1)
2016-09-11T15:23:13.640079+00:00 app[web.1]:     at server/main.ts:65:4
2016-09-11T15:23:13.723869+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Any Ideas please?

I have run: `meteor npm install --save`

I have found this in `boot.js`, but I am not sure what the author was doing.

```
    try {
      return require(name);
    } catch (e) {
      // Try to guess the package name so we can print a nice
      // error message
      // fileInfo.path is a standard path, use files.pathSep
      var filePathParts = fileInfo.path.split(files.pathSep);
      var packageName = filePathParts[1].replace(/\.js$/, '');

      // XXX better message
      throw new Error(
        "Can't find npm module '" + name +
          "'. Did you forget to call 'Npm.depends' in package.js " +
          "within the '" + packageName + "' package?");
      }
```

**UPDATE**

I removed the `.gitignore` of `node_modules/`, and I don't get any errors now.

[image]

However, I am new to Meteor, so not sure how to test this. But when I try invoke the app with `http://remote-thewhozoo.herokuapp.com/` or `https://remote-thewhozoo.herokuapp.com/` I get a 404 error:

```
2016-09-11T16:20:15.183895+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/sockjs/info?cb=jwgw2yuvgl" host=remote-thewhozoo.herokuapp.com request_id=a49fafb2-9708-46d2-8117-2c789bfa6a3e fwd="105.186.215.147" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=132
```

[image]

I do check the Mongo Database, and it has got the collections created by my app. So Meteor must be running, I just don't know how to access it.

[image]

Any ideas please?

Comment: My localhost is a Windows machine, and heroku is Linux. Is it maybe due to a case sensitivity issue or something?

Answer (score 12):

Make sure this line:`"moment": "^2.14.1"` is your package.json 
then run `npm install`

Comment: I just added the `package.json` to the question above. It does have `"moment": "^2.14.1"`

Comment: If issue is still presisting, I would do both `npm install -g moment` and `npm install moment` where the later is obviously in your meteor root directory.

Comment: I do try `meteor npm install --save moment` & `npm install -g moment` & `npm install moment`, but then when I try do a `git add/commit/push` it says no changes made.  `Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'` Any ideas please?

Comment: That should not be a problem. Usually changes in node_modules are not detected because they should get installed automatically from `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `meteor npm install` in your project root?

If moment didn't appear in that list, can you try `meteor npm install --save moment`?

Otherwise, could you please post your package.js - it should be in app/programs/server/

Comment: Thanks, I am busy trying that now. I am just doing the `git push`.  A quick question, is it correct to have a `gitignore` of `node_modules`?

Comment: That's fine, just remember to `npm install` every time you clone it to a new machine or pull after changing any dependencies.

Comment: I do try `meteor npm install --save moment`, but then when I try do a `git add/commit/push` it says no changes made.  `Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'` Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a problem with your buildpack. Try following this guide - https://meteorcoder.wordpress.com/2016/09/24/how-to-deploy-meteor-apps-with-heroku/

Answer (score 0):

I ran: npm install moment react-moment
& it worked. The official npm site has two different ways of installing this & they both gave me errors.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the error `"Cannot find module 'moment'"`, make sure to install the moment package by opening your terminal in your project's root directory and running the following command: `npm i moment` and restart your IDE and development server.