# Meteor on Heroku not working

Tags: meteor, heroku

I create a simple Meteor app:

```
meteor create test-meteor-app
cd test-meteor-app
meteor
```

meteor starts

Then I create a Heroku server.

```
git init
heroku git:remote -a remote-test-meteor-app
git add .
git commit -am "make it better"
git push heroku master
```

[image]

And I get:

```
2016-09-11T17:22:59.978392+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-09-11T17:22:59.978397+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-09-11T17:23:00.336281+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-09-11T17:23:01.911710+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-09-11T17:23:04.001360+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-09-11T17:23:04.014649+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-09-11T17:23:04.015767+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-09-11T17:23:03.941425+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-09-11T17:23:03.941445+00:00 app[web.1]: > meteor run
2016-09-11T17:23:03.941445+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-09-11T17:23:03.946773+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: meteor: not found
2016-09-11T17:23:03.957464+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-93-generic
2016-09-11T17:23:03.957967+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v5.11.1
2016-09-11T17:23:03.958306+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
2016-09-11T17:23:03.959375+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2016-09-11T17:23:03.959909+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the test-meteor-app@ start script 'meteor run'.
2016-09-11T17:23:03.960274+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-09-11T17:23:03.960395+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2016-09-11T17:23:03.960517+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     meteor run
2016-09-11T17:23:03.960618+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2016-09-11T17:23:03.960743+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs test-meteor-app
2016-09-11T17:23:03.960864+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2016-09-11T17:23:03.961118+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls test-meteor-app
2016-09-11T17:23:03.961242+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2016-09-11T17:23:03.964862+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-09-11T17:23:05.446417+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-09-11T17:23:07.415275+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-09-11T17:23:07.447458+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-09-11T17:23:07.323157+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-09-11T17:23:07.323177+00:00 app[web.1]: > meteor run
2016-09-11T17:23:07.323177+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-09-11T17:23:07.328685+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: meteor: not found
2016-09-11T17:23:07.333342+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-09-11T17:23:07.340269+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-93-generic
2016-09-11T17:23:07.340769+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v5.11.1
2016-09-11T17:23:07.341215+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
2016-09-11T17:23:07.341469+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2016-09-11T17:23:07.341799+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2016-09-11T17:23:07.342058+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! test-meteor-app@ start: `meteor run`
2016-09-11T17:23:07.342157+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2016-09-11T17:23:07.342292+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2016-09-11T17:23:07.342424+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the test-meteor-app@ start script 'meteor run'.
2016-09-11T17:23:07.342651+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the test-meteor-app package,
2016-09-11T17:23:07.342758+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-09-11T17:23:07.342853+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2016-09-11T17:23:07.343072+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2016-09-11T17:23:07.343180+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs test-meteor-app
2016-09-11T17:23:07.343300+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2016-09-11T17:23:07.343707+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2016-09-11T17:23:07.346956+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-09-11T17:23:07.347262+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
```

Then I try access the remote app via a browser and get a 503:

> remote-test-meteor-app.herokuapp.com

```
2016-09-11T17:26:19.347339+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=remote-test-meteor-app.herokuapp.com request_id=c3ad6369-00f9-4b16-98b8-ec5bb5a6605b fwd="105.186.215.147" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-09-11T17:26:21.133873+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=remote-test-meteor-app.herokuapp.com request_id=ec8e8ea9-af47-4cf8-9aac-1c897b4b4e70 fwd="105.186.215.147" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-09-11T17:26:21.436871+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=remote-test-meteor-app.herokuapp.com request_id=81d5cd8e-4164-4588-84fc-b0ffbcde51ad fwd="105.186.215.147" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Any ideas appreciated please?

**UPDATE**

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test-meteor-app",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "meteor-node-stubs": "~0.2.0"
  } 
}
```

Comment: Could you include the contents of your package.json?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. See above, I added it. It's  the file generate by `meteor create test-meteor-app`. I do not modify any code. I want to keep this as simple as possible, to test if it's possible to deploy a Meteor app to Heroku.

Answer (score 2):

You should try using the [Meteor buildpack](https://github.com/jordansissel/heroku-buildpack-meteor), which includes all of the system dependencies a Meteor application needs to run (node, the meteor binary, etc.).

```
heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/jordansissel/heroku-buildpack-meteor.git
```

See [this](https://medium.com/@leonardykris/how-to-run-a-meteor-js-application-on-heroku-in-10-steps-7aceb12de234#.o77dqq1la) blog post for a detailed tutorial.

Comment: Thanks. I have actually tried [this][1], but get these errors:  [see this][2]    [1]: https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39413119/error-cant-find-npm-module-moment

Comment: Strange, I follow the tutorial excactly, but get the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39439146/meteor-on-heroku-deployment

Answer (score 0):

The same problem. Here is the solution. You can either restart the heroku repository using `heroku run meteor restart` or you can reinstall the app using the steps described here : https://medium.com/@leonardykris/how-to-run-a-meteor-js-application-on-heroku-in-10-steps-7aceb12de234 .

I reinstalled the app and it works