# Meteor on Heroku Deployment

Tags: meteor, heroku, npm

I am trying to deploy Meteor to a remote Heroku server. I am following [this](https://medium.com/@leonardykris/how-to-run-a-meteor-js-application-on-heroku-in-10-steps-7aceb12de234#.ajit0vscz) tutorial, but get errors. Any advise would be appreciated please.

When I do the `git push heroku master`:

[image]

However, the server logs:

```
2016-09-11T18:03:14.757898+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-09-11T18:03:14.757903+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-09-11T18:03:41.646676+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node build/bundle/main.js`
2016-09-11T18:03:44.098961+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-09-11T18:03:44.099230+00:00 app[web.1]: assert.js:93
2016-09-11T18:03:44.099458+00:00 app[web.1]:   throw new assert.AssertionError({
2016-09-11T18:03:44.101174+00:00 app[web.1]: AssertionError: "undefined" === "function"
2016-09-11T18:03:44.101176+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/build/bundle/programs/server/mini-files.js:108:24)
2016-09-11T18:03:44.101177+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
2016-09-11T18:03:44.101178+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2016-09-11T18:03:44.101179+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
2016-09-11T18:03:44.101180+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
2016-09-11T18:03:44.173228+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8
2016-09-11T18:03:44.193642+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-09-11T18:03:44.194826+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-09-11T18:04:02.230596+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node build/bundle/main.js`
2016-09-11T18:04:04.559800+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8
2016-09-11T18:04:04.471328+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-09-11T18:04:04.471593+00:00 app[web.1]: assert.js:93
2016-09-11T18:04:04.473451+00:00 app[web.1]:     at wrapPathFunction (/app/build/bundle/programs/server/mini-files.js:77:10)
2016-09-11T18:04:04.473452+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/build/bundle/programs/server/mini-files.js:108:24)
2016-09-11T18:04:04.473453+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
2016-09-11T18:04:04.473454+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
2016-09-11T18:04:04.473455+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
2016-09-11T18:04:04.581922+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

**UPDATE**

I now try [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@gautham.gg/deploy-a-meteor-1-3-application-to-heroku-cda1f68ca20a#.q7rn4me1u) with a vanilla meteor app:

```
meteor create meteor-thewhozoo
```

But when I try `push` it to the Heroku server:

[image]

I have read that adding the Mongo Database eliminates the request for Credit Card info, but it didn't work for me.

```
heroku config:set MONGO_URL=mongodb://<dbname>:<password>@ds021026.mlab.com:21026/mongo-thewhozoo
```

I want to avoid giving my card details for a development environment/proof of concept.

**UPDATE**

Card details can be avoided. Read [this](https://medium.com/meteor-js/deploying-and-hosting-meteor-on-heroku-mongolab-for-free-37050a3ebd7e#.pa08h26t9), (see Setting up the build back).

Comment: I have created another Meteor app on Heroku, but don't know how to access it, or test that it's running. If anyone can advise please, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39413119/error-cant-find-npm-module-moment

Answer (score 1):

I recently was trying to deploy my meteor app to Heroku for the first time the other day. I followed this tutorial and it worked no problem.

https://medium.com/@gautham.gg/deploy-a-meteor-1-3-application-to-heroku-cda1f68ca20a#.wceub1sm3

Hope this helps.

Comment: Same error or different error? Just to check did you add a meteor build pack?

Comment: I get the following error:  'Push rejected to meteor-thewhozoo'. I will add an update to the Question above. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add card details by using mlab sandbox option for the database & that will give you 500MB slug size (which is more than sufficient for a dev environment).

You can pick the mlab sandbox db from heroku cli using the following command.

```
$ heroku addons:create mongolab:sandbox
```